# Cannot see newly created Publishing pages in Pages library

Tags: powershell, publishing-page

I have created a few publishing pages in Pages library using powershell.
When I go to the Pages library I don't see them via the UI.
However, I can see them via powershell script.

If I go to Site Content and I look at the Pages library, I see the number of items is 57, but when I go inside the library I am able to browse only 46.

The user that I am logged in is:
Site Collection administrator,
belongs in the Onwers group for this library,
I have added it in the Approvers and other appropriate groups, but still I can't see the items.

What am I missing? I have run out of ideas. Some help will be very much appreciated.

Edit 1: 
I have checked the default view and there is no filtering. I have created another view just in case, still cannot see the items.

Comment: I think that new publishing pages are checked out by default. So you could try to check them in / publishing them using powershell. Or use the account that you ran the powershell script with in the UI.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user19952 I was able to make the connection. Yes, it was true! Powershell was running under a different user account then the one I had logged on. This was because I am sharing my environment with other people and we are using the same account. So someone must have logged in on Powershell using a different account.

From now on I will always include this in my powershell script to see which user is running the script:

```
$userRunningScript =  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
Write-Host "***************** User Account executing the script **************" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host $userRunningScript -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "******************************************************************" -ForegroundColor Green
```

I should had checked this long time ago.